# How to fix a CRC32 error with DynamoDB access from a MS Edge browser

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, microsoft-edge, crc32

Using AWS SDK 2.7.13. Code works fine on versions of Chrome, IE and Firefox. On Edge 15, I get CRC32 integrity check failed.

Anyone experiencing similar issue, know the cause and resolution?

I see from [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=447571) that I can turn off CRC error checks with the below, but I'd like to identify the cause and fix instead.

```
AWS.config(:dynamo_db_crc32 => false)
```

Answer (score 2):

The belief is that this is due to the way the CRC32 is computed, before or after gzipping, see:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1614

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/405

The fix I used was to include bowser for browser detection

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bowser/1.6.0/bowser.min.js"></script>
```

and in prep for the dynamoDB call, turn off CRC32 error checks if the client is on Edge.

```
  if (bowser.msedge ) {
    AWS.config.update({dynamoDbCrc32: false})
  }
```